# Django: conditionally override get_queryset

Tags: django

Django 1.11

I have two models. I would like to conditionally override the default behavior of their manager.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, 
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                related_name='tasks')
    protected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = TaskManager()
```

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TaskManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(protected=True)
```

Tasks where `protected = True` should be filtered from any query not explicitly asking for them (I am aware the Django docs advise against filtering on overrides of `get_queryset()`)

With the above code, any query on `project.tasks` returns all related tasks where `protected = False`, as expected.

**How can I conditionally override `get_queryset()` to return only related tasks where `protected = True`?  Something like: `project.protected_tasks` or `project.tasks.protected`?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with -- the idea is to go in the other direction. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this.

```
class Project():
    def protected_tasks(self):
        return Task.protected_tasks.filter(project=self.id)

class ProtectedTaskManager():
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProtectedTaskManager, self).get_queryset().filter(protected=True)

class TaskManager():
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TaskManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(protected=True)

class Task():
    objects = TaskManager()
    protected_tasks = ProtectedTaskManager()
```

`project.tasks` returns all tasks where `protected = False`

and `project.protected_tasks` returns the opposite